# Why are Java rules for protected access such as they are?

Tags: java

Consider following code:

```
public class Sup {
    protected void method(){}
}

//another package
class Sub extends Sup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sub().method();
        new Sup().method(); // does not compile
    }
}
```

My question is: why was it designed in such way that second call doesn't compile?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Why do you think it *should* compile?

Comment: OP does not think that it should compile. He is also not asking for the reason why the program does not compile. OP wants to know the reasons for this design choice in Java.

Comment: @Zabuza: Right; I always ask for explanations of things that work the way I expect them to.

Comment: @ScottHunter Why not, we all accepted that it works like this but you can be interested on convincing reasons for this design choice. This can help you understand the language better. That doesn't mean that you are against that decision, just that you don't have a good picture of the **why**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protected` is used mainly for **utility** and **helper methods** inside a class. They are not meant to be accessible from outside, like `private` methods.

However it could be necessary for an **extending** class to access those methods or even to modify them. So basically it is *like* `private`, whose right to exist should be clear, but you want to give extending classes the chance to also access it.

This scenario happens that frequent that they decided to include `protected` in the language. If you have other wishes or design suggestions, feel free to share them.

---

Here is the frequently quoted [overview table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

```
            | Class | Package | Subclass | Subclass | World
            |       |         |(same pkg)|(diff pkg)| 
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+——————————+————————
public      |   +   |    +    |    +     |     +    |   +     
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+——————————+————————
protected   |   +   |    +    |    +     |     +    |         
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+——————————+————————
no modifier |   +   |    +    |    +     |          |    
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+——————————+————————
private     |   +   |         |          |          |    

+ : accessible
blank : not accessible
```

---

Think of an example where you provide some `abstract` base class, like an `AbstractMap`. It could have a method which re-arranges internal things.

You could make the method `private` but you could also make it `protected` since an extending class could then change the re-arrange procedure by overwriting. This could be useful if the extending class has, because of its specific structure, additional knowledge which it can use to create a more efficient version of the method.

Answer (score 2):

## What the JLS says

The relevant part of the JLS says the following:

> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if Id denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> - If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id, where Q is an ExpressionName, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S.
> - If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, where E is a Primary expression, or by a method invocation expression E.Id(. . .), where E is a Primary expression, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1)

The call to the method of Sup it does not pass the second rule, as it is a superclass, rather than a subclass.

The call to Sub is the same class, so it passes the rule.

## Why it says this

Protected members are meant to be used from within the internal code of subclasses, so being able to access it from a different object subclass would allow you to affect the state of objects you should not be able to.